# html css wrapper is not center aligned in iphone safari

Tags: iphone, css, wrapper

[should be center-aligned website](http://www.pandamama.com/tsseafood1/intro.php)

I have built a website as above link, with wrapper center aligned properly in PC/Mac browsers. However, when running in iphone safari, it is left aligned, but not center aligned.

the wrapper code is:

```
#wrapper {
width: 939px;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 40px auto 5px auto;
padding-bottom: 50px;
```

}

Any ideas on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tryd:

```
#wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper <yourChildrenId/yourChildrenClass/yourChildrenTag>{
    display: inline-block;
    //or
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mini hack, but if you set meta content width to the widest centered div it forces the iPhone screen to be that wide and doesn't mess the div centering up.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=[widest centered div];"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper{
 width: 939px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Should do it. I dont know why you need the margin-top.? The provided link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry that I have changed the server link, now the link is correct.the margin top is required from users.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to support iPhone Safari or CSS3 compatible browsers, here's an elegant approach: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center