# The element won't be centered when displaying on mobile device and background won't be fixed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile

I have just finished my website and I got a problem when I open it on mobile device (I tested with iPad 2). The issue is that the container that contains every element is not aligned on the center of the page, it lies a little bit on the left. The second issue is that I fixed the background to be non-repeat but it doesn't work on mobile device

Note that everything is fine on PC. The problems occur only in mobile device.

I don't know how to post all the code here so I give you this URL which gets you through my website

http://flourishtech.freevar.com/

Please open it in mobile device to see the issues.

Comment: This website is not responsive. Your footer has `min-width: 1100px` set to it. you need to work in percentages and media queries for it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The background issue: Your website although works on mobile is not responsive, so safari  shows the entire website on the window. This creates your issue because the background is too small and it doesn't fit the entire page. The quick solution is to get a background that fir the full height or make the website responsive.

[For centering the website on ios, check this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072154/html-css-wrapper-is-not-center-aligned-in-iphone-safari)